# firefox mouse event not defined

Tags: jquery, firefox, events, mouse

I have a script for drawing on a canvas. I am adding an event listener on mousedown and remove the listener on mouse up. It is working on Chrome but not on Firefox.

the code is like this:

```js
  $('#sketchCanvas').on("mousedown", function () {
      $('#sketchCanvas').on("mousemove", drawSketch);
  });

  $('#sketchCanvas').on("mouseup", function () {
      $('#sketchCanvas').off("mousemove", drawSketch);
  });

  drawSketch = function (event) {
      $("#mouseXY").text("x: "+event.offsetX + " y: " + event.offsetY);
  };
```

```css
.redborder {
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="sketchCanvas" width="200" height="200" class="redborder"></canvas>
<br/>
<span id="mouseXY" class="redborder">mouse coordinates</span>
```

here is a jsfiddle example of the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/womvLmk5/14/

Any ideas why this is happening? what is wrong on the above code?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like so:

```
  drawSketch = function (event) {
      var eTgtPos = $(event.target).offset(),
          x = (event.offsetX || event.clientX - eTgtPos.left),
          y = (event.offsetY || event.clientY - eTgtPos.top);
      $("#mouseXY").text("x: "+x + " y: " + y);
  };
```

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/womvLmk5/23/)

The mouse event object *is* defined in Firefox, just `offsetX` and `offsetY` are not defined within that object.

I also changed this bit to handle the mouse leaving the sketch area:

```
  $('#sketchCanvas').on("mouseup mouseleave", function () {
      $('#sketchCanvas').off("mousemove", drawSketch);
  });
```

That makes it so the event turns off even if the mouseup event happens outside the canvas

HTH

Comment: thank you also for the correction with mouseleave. This solves a problem that I would have in a couple of days :-)

Comment: No problem, glad to be a help :)